# Angular SEO, how to set properly?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, seo

I have a little question about Angular SEO. I have set the meta tags like this in the constructors of every .ts file;

```
//To set the page title
this.titleServ.setTitle("PAGE TITLE")
//To set the meta description
this.meta.addTags([
  {name: "description", content: "PAGE TITLE HERE"},
  {name: "keywords", content: "SOME KEYWORDS HERE"}
])
```

The problem is that, I have made these changes like 2,5 weeks ago, but I still can not see my website on Google when searched with the descriptions from the pages (I can see it when I search the name of the website). What might I have done wrong in here?

Btw, I couldnt manage to build my application with angular universal, but as far as I have understood, Google does not need angular universal to find the description and the keywords.

What more should I do in order my website to be visible on Google?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after much researches I find out that Google has a problem finding URLs in SPAs.
You should build a `sitemap.xml` file and give it to Google Search Console.

sample sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot for this great information. I will try this as soon as possible and give your credits after than. Also, our urls are a little bit long, does this also effects the process?

Comment: @MichaelJordan 
URLs are a minor ranking factor search engines use when determining a particular page or resource's relevance to a search query. While they do give weight to the authority of the overall domain itself, keyword use in a URL can also act as a ranking factor.
So don't worry for urls length.

Comment: @MichaelJordan please add robots.txt as well as sitemap.xml